# Trocar tela (xml) com botão de login

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo. Nele se tem a opção de entrada por login. Queria saber como passar para outro layout xml quando login e senha validados.

O sistema de login já esta quase pronto. Eu coloquei na aba da `MainActivity`, fiz um `private void (oncreate)` configurando o botão, e após, em um `public void` o codigo "IF" coloquei para validar o login e senha e assim mostrar que o login foi realizado. Queria saber como trocar para outra tela XML com o botão a partir da validação do login.

Já tentei usar Intents para chamar outra `activity` dentro da regra if, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogin);
        btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tLogin);
                TextView tSenha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tSenha);
                String Login = tLogin.getText().toString();
                String Senha = tSenha.getText().toString();
                if(Login.equals("hugo")&&Senha.equals("123")) {
                    alert("Login realizado com sucesso");

                }
                else{
                    alert("Login ou senha incorretos");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void alert(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

A minha intenção era colocar nas chaves da regra if uma intent para chamar outro layout.

Comment: Hugo, poste também o código que vc está escrevendo, fica mais fácil pra te ajudar

Comment: Pronto, coloquei o código e o que estou tentando.

Comment: Coloque o Intent dentro do if enbaixo do alert

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você deve estar fazendo o Intent de forma errada, veja esse simples exemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

E você também deve se lembrar, de registrar a **SegundaActivity** no **AndroidManifest.xml**, exemplo:

```
<activity
     android:name=".SegundaActivity"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

Na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=pt-br) do Android você pode ver tudo como é feito.

Comment: Na segunda linha do primeiro codigo, "startActivity(intent);" eu devo colocar o nome da intent que criei?

startActivity(Usuarioconectado);

O nome da Intent que criei foi Usuarioconectado.class

Comment: Vc deve colocar o nome que vc criou pra sua variável intent, que no caso ali é **intent** mesmo, mas pode ser qualquer coisa, por exemplo: *Intent qualquer_nome = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);* e então *startActivity(qualquer_nome);*

Comment: "Error:(16, 23) error: cannot find symbol variable Intent"

Recebi esse erro, quando clico nele ele seleciona no arquivo java a palavra Intent em 
startActivity(Intent);

Comment: O nome da variável deve ser com letra minuscula, tenta colocar outro nome na variável que nnao seja *intent*

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
  
Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actButton);
        btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText tLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
                    EditText tSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);
                    String Login = tLogin.getText().toString();
                    String Senha = tSenha.getText().toString();
                    if(Login.equals("hugo")&&Senha.equals("123")) {
                        alert("Login realizado com sucesso");
                        Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Uni.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Login ou senha incorretos");
                        alert("Volta");
                        
                    }
                    
                        
                    

                }
            });
    }

   private void alert(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pode até resolver, mas o que faz e como usar sua solução?